# pywin32 not loading in properly

Tags: pywin32, python-3.11

I am trying to install pywin32 to use the win32com.client function in python 3. I'm using a windowns computer running windows 10. This is also a work computer so doing anything requiring admin privileges  means contacting IT. I have python 3.11 installed and had a version of pywin32 installed but removed it to install an older version to test something. When that didn't work, I tried to reinstall pywin32 version 306.

In command, I put in "pip install pywin32" and that returns
"Collecting pywin32
Using cached pywin32-306-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (9.2 MB)
Installing collected packages: pywin32
Successfully installed pywin32-306"

After that I run "py -m pywin32_postinstall -install" and that throws the error
"ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified procedure could not be found."

I've tried uninstalling the package and renaming the old pythoncom311 and pywintypes311 DLLs and then resintalling and it still doesn't work. I've tried restarting everything, I've tried looking for the cached version but couldn't find it.

Please help!

Comment: Use https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest or  https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html to create virtual environments in accessible locations so you won't have to beg paranoid IT services for mercy every time you need to install/uninstall a package. I can use the package without running the postinstall script.